# Accessing child elements in a function (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

jQuery

```
$("#myID").each(function() {
  $(this).dosomething;
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="myID">
 <div class="myClass">content</div>
</div>
```

How do I access myClass from the function? `this>myClass` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(this).children(".myClass")
```